# how to let right side child flow next to left side child of a horizontal layout

Tags: android, layout

outer parent linear layout has limited width, and three children:

```
[child A][<-   child b           ->][child c]
```

for child b it has two children

```
[<-   child b                ->]
[element 1][element 2]
```

would like the child 2 flow by child 1, and if not enough space then child one should show ellipsis

```
[<-   child b                ->]
[element 1    xxx...][element 2]
```

tried following layout, when the child 1 is too long it takes all space and pushes child 2 out of view.

```
[<-   child b                ->]
[element 1  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...]
```

if specify child 1 has

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

in the case child 1 has short content then the child 2 does not flow by it, instead child 2 aligns to right side.

```
[<-   child b                ->]
[element 1]          [element 2]
```

And don't want to give a hard coded maxWidth for child 1.
any suggestion?

```
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight=“3dp”
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />

            <TextView                    
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of, if not create custom ViewGroup or change width in code.

Set both with wrap_content and set `maxWidth` for the first TextView to a safe number such that it would not push away the second TextView.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight=“3dp”
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <TextView                    
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it does not. if the child 1 is too long it pushes out the child 2.

Comment: thank, cannot hard code the maxWidth. And was trying to avoid dynamically calc the max width as well.

Answer (score 0):

just having a similar case and with this layout it works.

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"

        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"


        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:text="Tap to change"

        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_dropdown"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```